# how to make jquery only display in correct class div with ajax request?

Tags: jquery

I have made this simple jquery script to check forms for me...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loading').hide();    
});

function check_username(){
    var username = $("#username").val();
    $('.loading').show();
    $.post("ajax.php", {
        username: $('#username').val(),
    }, function(response){
        $('.info').fadeOut();
        $('.loading').hide();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('info', '"+escape(response)+"')", 450);
    });
    return false;
}

function check_email(){
    var email = $("#email").val();
    $('.loading').show();
    $.post("ajax.php", {
        email: $('#email').val(),
    }, function(response){
        $('.info').fadeOut();
        $('.loading').hide();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('info', '"+escape(response)+"')", 450);
    });
    return false;
}

function finishAjax(id, response){
    $('.'+id).html(unescape(response));
    $('.'+id).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Only thing is when there is an error on the post username the error displays in all the error boxes and not the one assigned to username, anyway to stop this without assigning ids to all the divs for use of practicality.

Comment: Please... NEVER pass a string to `setTimeout` - you can pass a function: `setTimeout(function() { finishAjax('info', response) }, 450);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `.`, that's a class selector not an id.  You should not use strings when calling `setTimeout`.  Do;

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    finishAjax('info', response);
}, 450);
```

That eliminates the need for escaping.  However, it is not clear why you're using `setTimeout` at all.

For your actual question, you can use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) instead of setting up a separate element.  And pass the actual id of the form element:

E.g.

```
finishAjax('username', response);

function finishAjax(id, response){
    $('#'+id).after(response).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

You can hide loading initially with CSS:

```
.loading
{
  display: none;
}
```

instead of your `ready` block.

Since you're using jQuery, you may want to look into the [jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin.

Comment: Thanks this should do the trick, thanks for the plugin but I don't use them I like to learn it the hard way before using things I don't understand ;)

Comment: @carl, that's a good philosophy, and why I put the rest of the JS and CSS tips first. :)

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with setting IDs for the divs? Using jQuery you should probably use IDs as often as you can instead of classes due to the better performance.

If you absolutely do not want to do that, there are other ways to access nodes in the DOM. For example if you have some HTML-structure like

```
<input type="text" id="username" />
<div class="info">The error message for username.</div>
```

You could simply do `$('#username').next()`  to access the div, without using it's class name.